# React/Redux - When should you fetch new data from an API to update your store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, frontend

I'm trying to get a handle on what is best practice when it comes to updating/refreshing your Redux state with data from an API.

Think of this scenario:

You have a To Do app where a number of users are potentially updating the same To Do's as you at any given point in time. Obviously you'll want your local Redux store to reflect these changes from the other users eventually.

Would you:

- Fetch the updated set of To Do's on route change?
- Fetch an updated version of that To Do when/if the user makes changes to the To Do or interacts with it?
- Both?
- Never - you keep the state in the store once fetched and it becomes the source of truth for that session (obviously not ideal)
- Something else?

I'm not interested in pushing changes to the client right now nor polling an API (ugh!). I'm simply interested in gaining some sort of consensus as to when most developers refresh API derived data that is stored in their Redux state.

Comment: Just a try: If you are not changing the route or interacting with the app even then the app store should update. Ideal time according to me is the beginning of the app. When your first component is going to render. And while fetching we should not unsubscribe the fetching, as in case of firebase, whenever there is some change in the data it should update the store.

Comment: Even not in the beginning. Where ever you are fetching your data donot unsubscribe it

Comment: But if I'm not pushing data to the client (as per question), then there is no opportunity to subscribe/unsubscribe. I'm simply making a fetch() call to grab the data. I do this when the app first loads (for some app wide specific data such as account details/users/etc) and then I fetch the "to dos" when a user clicks on the "to dos" route. At present, I re-fetch the data when the user goes BACK to the "to dos" route.

Comment: subscription is related to fetching of data not pushing. When you are on current component and you can use subscription to fetch data in continous manner and when you leave the component you unsubscribe  it.but when you revisit that page you have to fetch data again so that you get updated one. so i think re fetching not a extra job.

Comment: you just have to add a subscription when user goes to 'to dos' route

Comment: How exactly do you think I can implement a subscription architecture simply using fetch()? I don't want to poll the server nor am I using RxJS in conjunction with some other libraries. I'm talking about basic React with Redux and Redux Thunk. Maybe elaborate on your suggested solution with a small block of code explaining how you think this works?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to push nor poll, then fetch data when the user request it. Never fetching may be well suited for edge case application but definitly not a common use case.

Comment: You're on the same page as me and I completely agree. What would you class as "when the user requests it"? Would you add say a "refresh to dos" button for example or maybe re-fetch the data when the user changes back to a route that displays all of the to dos? ...or maybe both?

Comment: Yes primarily on route change, you can add an extra refresh button if you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I got from your question

1. Same space in your app is updated by multiple user.
2. Any user who is on the app must get the changes done by other user.
3. You want to know when to fetch data or refresh your store.

> I'm not interested in pushing changes to the client right now nor
>   polling an API (ugh!).

I am not getting it what is this for. You may not be updating the app but to see the changes your app should be updated by one or other.

Apart from this I told you to subscribe the fetching of data wherever you are fetching it. I don't know what you understood by subscription, according to me subscription is to keep on doing fetching at regular interval to get updates. Subscription is async in nature.

I am giving a simple example of implementing subscription.

```
console.log("Started");
let subscription = false;
const getData = () => {
  // call your database and fetch the data and once
  // fetching done call the getData again

 // Think setTimeout as database call.
 // upon resolving the data I called it again
 // It neither stops other call back from running run
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Fetching");
    if(subscription) {
      console.log("shuting");
      return;
    }
    getData();
  }, 1000);
}

getData();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("hello");
}, 5000);

setTimeout(() => {
  subscription = true;
}, 8000);
```